# Copy data from POD vector to vector of bytes (cleanly)

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have a vector of floats that I want to "serialize", for the lack of a better term, into a vector of bytes, i.e.

```
std::vector<float> myFloats = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
std::vector<unsigned char> myBytes;
```

Right now, I `memcpy` float to a `uint32_t` variable, and the do bit shifting and masking to insert one byte at a time into `myBytes`.

Since memory in these two is contiguous, is there a way for me to do it more cleanly?

Comment: Both answers below are good, but assume that the data will be deserialized on a system with the same endianess.  Most systems these days seem to favor little-endian data, but if you are sending this to an unknown system, you need to be careful.  There are embedded systems (especially networking machines) that still use big endian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allowed to use `unsigned char *` to alias into other types without violating strict aliasing, so the following will work

```
std::vector<float> myFloats = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
std::vector<unsigned char> myBytes{reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(myFloats.data()),
                                   reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(myFloats.data() + myFloats.size())};
```

You're making use of the [`vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes two iterators

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Comment: I dont think this will work, since myFloats.size() is only 4, but each float takes more than one byte, in your example you will only copy the first float (in a 32bit system). I think this should be myFloats.data() + (myFloats.size() * sizeof(float)) for the end iterator.

Comment: @AngelCastillo That's not how pointer math works. `myFloats.data()` returns a `float *` to the first `float`, and incrementing that by 4 will result in a pointer that points to one past the last `float` in the `vector`. Your suggested solution will attempt to copy 16 `float`s (assuming `sizeof(float) == 4`

Comment: @Preatorian That would be true for a pointer to float*, but your are casting the pointer to "unsigned char*", that constructor will increment that pointer by "unsigned char" size, not "float" size, the end result will be that the pointer will move 1 byte at a time four times. Run the code and you will see. As for my suggested solution, memcpy takes void* as parameters, thats why I multyply by sizeof(float)

Comment: @AngelCastillo Placement of parentheses makes a world of difference, I'm incrementing the `float *` and then casting, not the other way around. If you're still not convinced, try it out yourself.

Comment: @Preatorian Hah, you are right, my mistake I did not read the code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned char>
getByteVector(const std::vector<float>& floats)
{
  std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(floats.size() * sizeof(float));
  std::memcpy(&bytes[0], &floats[0], bytes.size());

  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but be aware that the vector constructor will value initialize (zero initialize) all the `unsigned char`s, before you overwrite them with the `memcpy`, so there's that added cost.